# why two level PHP include only work on current directory?

Tags: php, php-include

Let me demonstrate my file structure first.

```
/www/
    myfile.php
    anotherC.php
     a/
       b.php
       c.php
```

The code inside `myfile.php` is:

```
<?php
    include_once("a/b.php");
?>
```

The code inside `b.php` is:

```
<?php
    include_once("c.php");
?>
```

And finally inside `c.php`:

```
<?php
   echo "hello i'm C.php";
?>
```

So, when I call `www/myfile.php` I get output:

> hello i'm C.php

These works fine. But let me change `b.php` to

```
<?php
     include_once("../anotherC.php"); //or include_once("./c.php"); (it won't work too)
?>
```

Now, when I call `www/myfile.php`, i get Error:

> Warning: include_once(../anotherC.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in /home/hasib/Desktop/www/a/b.php on line 2
>   Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../anotherC.php' for
>   inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/hasib/Desktop/www/a/b.php on line 2

Now my question is, why The `include_once("c.php");` **worked perfectly??**

Comment: What's your include_path set to?

Comment: My recommendation: use absolute paths, starting from the document root (`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`). The advantages are: you save yourself from headaches; You can move the files around without caring to change the paths in the actual code; If you delete intermediary files you still can access to the desired file from the last one. etc...

Comment: @AlexHowansky, my include path is .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear

Comment: Is not the answer I know.@aleation: I pefer using ``include_once dirname(__FILE__)."/relative/path/file.php";`` instead of DOCUMENT_ROOT works also if not called by webserver.

Answer (score 1):

the [document](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing.
>
> If a path is defined — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter or \ on Windows, or / on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the current directory (starting with . or ..) — the include_path will be ignored altogether. For example, if a filename begins with ../, the parser will look in the parent directory to find the requested file.

the 'calling script' in your example is b.php , obviously it's directoy is '/www/a/'.

you can use getcwd() to get the 'current directory', either in myfile.php or b.php ,it will return '/www/'

so when include_once("c.php"); it first look up c.php in calling script's directory,that is /www/a/ , and get c.php successfully.

when include_once("../anotherC.php"); , it only look up anotherC.php in relative path to current directory, current directory is /www/ , so it look up anotherC.php in / , /anotherC.php doesn't exists and throw warning.

Comment: In the second case when `include_once("../anotherC.php")`, why the current directory is `/www/`??? Isn't it be `/www/a/` as you stated before??



(And as far as I know, the current directory would be always "/www/" [in both cases] where the currently executing file(`myfile.php`) exists.)

Comment: @HasibAlMuhaimin please notice the differece between 'current directory' and "calling script's directory" , you can get 'current directory' by getcwd() as I said,the result is alway /www/ as yu know.

Comment: @HasibAlMuhaimin if a path is start with .. (just like ../anotherC.php),php only look up the relative path to 'current directory'

Answer (score 0):

Includes with relative paths are always done relative to the MAIN script. `include()` operates essentially the same way as if you'd cut 'n pasted the included data directly into the main script. So when your sub-includes are performed, they're using the working directory of your `myFile.php` script, NOT the working directory of `b.php` or `c.php`.

Your sub-scripts would need to have an absolute path in their icnldues, or at least some kind of "where the heck am I" determination code, e.g. `include(__FILE__ . 'c.php')`

Comment: This does not answer the question: *Why did `include("c.php")` work*?

Comment: yep, why `include("c.php")` worked?? After looking around php.net, now I know how to include files safely. But, how the `include("c.php")` worked while it is supposed to not work.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of for this working is that you have `/www/a` in your `include_path`. This means that `include_once("c.php")` would first look for `/www/c.php` (since that's the current working directory), then look for `/www/a/c.php` which would be found and work.

However, `include_once("./c.php")` explicitly states to look in the current working directory only, and of course since the file is not there, it won't work.

Comment: :( As far as I know my include-path is `.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear`